# How can I enforce a 3rd party dll to use a newer version of another dll in my solution?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, console-application, versioning

I have a console application that references foo.dll. And foo.dll -as well as my console- references another dll which is boo.dll.

Console application references --> **boo.dll** AND **fool.dll**
foo.dll also references --> **boo.dll** but it specifies the version number: '1.2.0'

Now, imagine that I have replaced boo.dll with the newer version. '1.3.0'

Now, as foo.dll references boo.dll by specifying the version number to be 1.2.0 my solution does not build anymore.

**How can I enforce foo.dll to use newer version of boo.dll**? Can I achive this via app.config?

Thanks

Comment: How can you ensure that the 3rd party foo.dll will work with the newer version of boo.dll if both of these assemblies are out of your control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a [binding redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eftw1fys.aspx) in your config file.  This will attempt to up-version all the boo.dll references to the defined version.